# Recalculating and Repositioning Elements on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I am a web design student and I am working on my portfolio site.  I have a resume page that has a non-traditional design or layout. The problem I am running into occurs when the page is resized. Certain elements are pushed down as the window gets smaller. I need to find a way to adjust their top margin as the resize occurs, but I have not been able to accomplish this with media queries alone. Please see the following codepen for an example of the issue I am running into.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hkpny

As the browser goes below 1440px, the boxes hanging from the ropes start to push down. Is there a way to use javascript to recalculate the margin-top and apply it to the elements when the user reduces or increases the window resize? The ultimate goal is to have the ropes stay connected where the red dots have been placed because I am going to give the hanging boxes a subtle swing or sway animation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please explain me how this percentage thing works, because it kinda would make css suck a lot less for me if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a whole lot easier if you did one background image rather than trying to keep all the image perfectly aligned as they scale?  The one scaled background image would never get out of alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get it, all I had to do is to is what you did but for `margin-top`. You may want to play a bit with the values because I've never used scss before in my life (I'd do it with a `<canvas>` and javascript to begin with), but it works. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iJgqn

Btw if you plan to display it in landscape mode on mobile, you may want to cut the shields left and right or it may get scaled very small. Maybe put them under the big shield in that case and get as much zoom on the rest as possible.

Comment: I didn't realize that you could calculate the vertical margins with percentages based on the width like that. This was a simple solution that both me and my teacher completely missed. As for the mobile devices, I agree that this layout won't work. I planned on making adjustments to the design for those devices. Thanks! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

For a portfolio site I would recommend reconsidering the whole design.  Just from this snippet, it seems the design is not very accessible and has too many dependencies.  The concept is pretty cool but while you want to showcase your skills and creativity, you also want to showcase your understanding for accessibility (responsiveness), usability and what is trending right now (clean, minimal and flat design).  I'm not saying you should fall in line and design what everyone else is, but you need to attract clients which is the whole purpose of a portfolio.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions. For the most part, my projects displayed on my site are geared toward the modern, minimal design. I just wanted to do something a bit different when it comes to my resume page. Winchestro was able to help me out with a simple oversight so hopefully I don't have to scrap this entire design.  Thanks again for the suggestions.

Comment: No problem.  Comments aside, I like what you're doing.  Good luck.